# CSS fails after changing orientation

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Here is the CSS for mobile devices

```
@media(max-device-width: 480px)
    {html{font-size: 2px}
    #Logo{line-height: 25px; position: absolute; top: 2%; left: 65%; text-align:centre; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 40px; 
           padding-bottom: 10px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
    #sub{ text-align: center; display:block; position: absolute; top: 45% ; left: 25%; font-size: 20px; font-family: Airstrike; padding-bottom:0px; color: whitesmoke}
    #header{width: 250%}
    #Welcome{font-size: 15px}
    #main{font-size: 12px}
    #GetPic{width: 5vw}
    #ProducMax{display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 90% ; left: 55%; font-size: 23px}
    }}

    @media (orientation: portrait) and (max-device-width: 480px)
    {html{font-size: 2px}
    #Logo{line-height: 25px; position: absolute; top: 2%; left: 75%; text-align:centre; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 30px; 
           padding-bottom: 10px; vertical-align: middle;}
    #sub{ text-align: center; display:block; position: absolute; top: 50% ; left: 25%; font-size: 15px; font-family: Airstrike; padding-bottom:0px; color: whitesmoke}
    #header{width: 260%}
    #Welcome{font-size: 15px}
    #main{ font-size: 12px}
    #GetPic{width: 5vw}
    #ProducMax{display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 90% ; left: 55%; font-size: 23px}
    }}
```

Here is the Global and Tablet CSS file

```
@font-face {font-family: 'Neutronium'; src: url('fonts/divlit.ttf');}
@font-face{font-family: 'Hemi'; src: url('fonts/hemi_head_bd_it.ttf')}
@font-face{font-family: 'Airstrike'; src: url('fonts/airstrike.ttf')}
@font-face{font-family: 'MantaRayJack'; src: url('fonts/VertigoFLF.ttf')}


    html{margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 10px}
    #header{background-color: #020249; line-height: 20px; display: block; color: whitesmoke; margin-bottom: 0px;}
    #Logo{ line-height: 25px; text-align: right; position: absolute; top: 2%; left: 30%; white-space: nowrap; 
    font-size: 80px; font-family: Airstrike; padding-bottom: 15px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
    #sub{position: relative; top: 5%; text-align: center; font-size: 30px; font-family: Airstrike; padding-bottom:0px;}
    body{margin: 0px; font-family: MantaRayJack; font-size: 1vw; background: url(images/Aluminium.jpg); background-size: cover; width: auto}
    #Welcome{text-align: center; font-size: 2.5rem; font-family: Hemi; margin: 0px;}
    #Services{text-align: center; display: block; padding-top: 0px}
    #Defense{text-align: center; display: block; padding-top: 30px}
    #Consult{text-align: center; display: block; padding-top: 30px}
    #good{text-align: center; font-size: 2.3rem; font-family: Hemi; padding: 5px; color: whitesmoke}
    #Hello{ font-size: 2rem; font-family: Hemi}
    nav{background-color: #020249; float: left; margin-top: 0; padding: 10px; position: relative; top: 10%; margin-right: 10px}
    #ProducMax{display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 90% ; left: 30%; font-size: 28px}
    }

    @media(orientation: portrait) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (min-device-width: 1000px)
    {
    #Logo{position: absolute; left: 20%; top: 2%; font-size: 75px; line-height: 15px}
    #header{width: 110%}
    #ProducMax{display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 45% ; left: 37%; font-size: 28px}
    }

    @media(orientation: landscape) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (min-device-width: 1000px)
    {#header{width: 102%}
    #Logo{position: absolute; left: 20%; top: 2%; font-size: 80px; line-height: 20px}
    #ProducMax{display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 70% ; left: 38%; font-size: 28px}
    }
```

And here is the HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MuGa Digital Solutions</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newcss.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" media="(max-device-width: 800px)">
    </head>
    <div id="header">
   <div id="Photo"><img src="images/LogoD.jpg" style="width:16vw; vertical-align: middle; white-space: nowrap; display: block"></div><div id="Logo">MuGa Digital Solutions
            <br><br><br> <div id="sub">A division of Mukherjee-Garg</div></div>
    </div>

    <body>
        <br><br>
        <nav>
        <br><div id="good">Divisions</div>
        <br><div id="Services"><a href="Services.html"><img src="images/Services.png" style="height: auto; width: 12rem"></a></div>
        <div id="Consult"><a href="Consult.html"><img src="images/Digital_Consultancy.png" style="height: auto; width: 12rem"></a></div>
         <div id="Defense"><a href="Defense.html"><img src="images/Untitled-1.png" style="height: auto; width: 12rem;"></a></div>
        </nav>
        <div id="Welcome">Welcome to the home of MuGa Digital  Solutions,
               a Non-Profit organization committed to providing easy-to-use software to enhance and enrich everyday lives</div>
        <br><br>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="Hello">
            <center><h1>Our Software</h1></center>
            <br><center><h3><div style="font-size: 30px"><u>Productivity Max</u></div></h3></center>
            </div>
            <br><div id="GetPic"><left><img src="images/GETERDONE.jpg" style="width: 17vw; vertical-align: middle"></left></div>
                <div id="ProducMax">Productivity Max is a simple personal activity planner with a small twist. Productivity Max calculates how much time 
                you should spend per activity, taking into account all of your regular activities in a day such as meals, breaks and work/school. In 
                addition, Productivity Max is also able to suggest what changes you should make to your regular activities to make more time for other 
                activities, thus making yourself more productive! Which has been our ultimate goal with Productivity Max.
                <br><br><center><a href="ProductivityMax.html"><u>Click here for more info</u></a></center></div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Me and my friend are developing a website, and we have a problem. When I load the page, all the CSS is applied and the site looks fine, when I rotate the orientation, everything is still fine. When I rotate back to portrait however, all the CSS inside the media queries for **480px device-width** devices in portrait orientation, inside the CSS file for mobile devices stops working and it goes to the default CSS again.

Here's the catch. If I go back to landscape, it works again. I'm not sure how to explain the issue much further. I'm quite amateur in CSS and Stack Overflow so please pardon my messy code and the unorganized nature of this question.

All help is appreciated,
thank you.

Comment: i never see something like this `{html{font-size: 2px}`

Comment: @Sunny have you handed the media query for the **landscape orientation** for the 480px device/.?>

Comment: set proper mediaquries @sunny

Comment: Try to use   $(window).resize(); function

Comment: Technically we should avoid using ` @media(orientation: portrait)` and something like that, as @Hunter said, use proper `media-queries` for better results.
writing `CSS` on the basis of `width` is more enough for making a good responsive website.

Comment: if you have coded for portrait orientation than you can also code for landscape orientation to get output